# How can I change my page's Master Page at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

There is a requirement in one of my project, where I need to change Master Page during run time.

I mean I need to apply check and on the basis of that check particular master page can be called to my native aspx page.

Please help me out for same.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/asp.net-2.0/changing-master-pages-dynamically-in-asp.net-2.0.html

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMaster.master";
}
```

Apply your conditionals as required. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.ASPX).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set the MasterPageFile property only during the PreInit page event—that is, before the runtime begins working on the request (since the rendering of the page with the master page occurs prior to the Init event)

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       MasterPageFile = "simple2.master";
}
```

If you try to set the MasterPageFile property in Init or Load event handlers, an exception is raised.

Yes it is possible, Implement like below

[Dynamically Loading Master Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/06/16/788.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To acheive this we need to write code in Page_PreInit before page gets render.

Put below code into your code behind:

```
if (Session["userType"] == "Admin") //check the user type
    this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/Admin.master";
 else
    this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/User.master";
```

Hope this helps.